# Travel to Europe countries amidst COVID-19

Tags: paperwork, schengen-visas, spain, itineraries, covid-19

I have got Spain visa for 1 month duration based on the itinerary and other documents that I submitted. In the itinerary I mentioned that Spain will be the point of entry, followed by France and Netherlands. However with the intensive spread of corona virus in Spain and France, I have decided not to travel to those two countries and instead travel to country that is less affected by corona and the country that falls in Schengen visa entry.

Please let me know if I’m allowed to do refrain from travelling to Spain and go to some other Schengen country.

Comment: WHich country do you want to enter first now? I recommend you to e-mail that country's border control, explain your situation and ask

Comment: @MarkJohnson I can confirm that answer is far from "safe" as a blanket answer. It will very much depend on the specific member state; a few almost certainly would refuse entry and flag OP for visa fraud, saying they should've had the visa cancelled and applied for a new one

Comment: @Crazydre I doubt that very much. Visa  fraud is the last thing, in this specific situation, that will be of high consern. Very soon, general travel will be disencuraged where avoidable.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Either way I've been told this by a few countries' border HQs, including in my own country

Comment: Any answer to this question can only be opinion-based unless someone has been in the exact same circumstances.

Comment: @Traveller And since it a swiftly envolving situation, no one will nbe. Each person must make a decision for themselfs based on the available information. The answer to the linked question, is in mine, the best.

Comment: @Crazydre Claims of what you have been told are not a verifiable source and are not really helpfull. The Border Guards in Italy or Austria did make a decision that peaple can cross without restrictions, politicians and healt officials did.

Comment: @Mark Johnson I agree it’s up to the individual. Personally, in the current situation, I’d not want to travel on the back of advice from random strangers on the internet. If I had to choose I’d go with Crazydre’s comment, given it is based on contact with some border HQs. Isn’t the best advice eg to contact the visa-issuing consulate and ask for the visa to be revoked in favour of the new destination?

Comment: @Traveller Yes, but Crazydre the same claim many days ago. The situation has changed in the meantime. So his contraindications are based on out of date information.

Comment: @Prashanth I doubt anyone on TSE can give you a reliable answer.  Contact the Consulate that issued your visa and ask for their advice.

Comment: @Traveller Again, the consulate has **zero** say in what happens at the border. So again, my whole point is OP should e-mail the border control of the country of intended entry and ask for their advice

Comment: @Crazydre Sorry, my point was that the OP should try to get the visa revoked in favour of one that would definitively allow them to enter Greece. I agree with you about border control.

Comment: @Traveller If I were OP I wouldn't bother if border control tells me it's OK (I'd carry the e-mail printout, as national operational units are above local ports)